# Trying to setup facebook login : you must have a valid contact email specified to make this app available to all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to set up facebook login on my website.

**Website Url**
[MatchMaherFriend.com](http://www.matchmakerfriend.com)

But I am getting the following error when I am trying to make it live in the apps Status & Review section.

***you must have a valid contact email specified to make this app available to all users***

I have set my email in App Details section and also in setting.

Still the button is disabled.
Need help here

Thanks

Comment: Is the email address confirmed with Facebook?

Answer (score 31):

You must fill the "Contact Email".
This form is at:
Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email