# Submitting desktop website - Facebook integration for review

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have a Send to Friend button on facebook that goes to: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=...&...

After implementation I found out that it can't be used until I submit it for approval. So I went to my app admin page on Facebook and clicked on App Review. Then added submission for "Optimized Sharing for Messenger" - nothing else seemed to fit this case. I uploaded a recording while using the integration on my site, and added a description of how it will be used. Now it tells me:

- that my app should fire a ActivateApp event from within my mobile app,
- and also is asking to provide a Test User that Facebook review team will use.

I don't have a mobile app - it's just a desktop website integration, and don't know what a test user means in this context. I filled everything I could, but the "Submit for Review" button is still disabled.

Comment: You do __not__ need to submit your app for review, to use the simple Send button. (You might need to set your app _live_, if you have not already done that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approval is not necessary to use the send button. You do need a Facebook application created and set to public/live in the App Review portion of [the settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), but review is not required to do this. That's only required for [one of the extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the answers here and went to try and switch it to Live, but couldn't. Then noticed the little message on hover "You must have a valid contact email specified to make this app available to all users", then could not find where that email is (there are at least 5 different places with an email field). This answer solved my problems: [Trying to setup facebook login : you must have a valid contact email specified to make this app available to all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862486/trying-to-setup-facebook-login-you-must-have-a-valid-contact-email-specified-t)